# unusually high accuracy when running ML

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Hi I am working with a difficult data set, in that there is low correlation between  the input and output, yet results are very good (99.9% accuracy with the test set). I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, just don't know what.

label is 'unsafe' column, which is either 0 or 1 (was originally 0 or 100 but I limited the maximum value - it made no difference with the result. I started with random forests and then ran k nearest neighbors and got almost the same accuracy, 99.9%. Screenshots of df are:

[image]
[image]

there are many more 0s than 1s (in the training set out of 80,000 there are only 169 1s, and there is also a run of 1s at the end but this is just how the original file was imported)

```
import os
import glob

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sklearn
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_pickle('/Users/shellyganga/Downloads/ola.pickle')

maxVal = 1
df.unsafe = df['unsafe'].where(df['unsafe'] <= maxVal, maxVal)

print(df.head)

df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[-2], axis=1, inplace=True)

#setting features and labels
labels = np.array(df['unsafe'])
features= df.drop('unsafe', axis = 1)

# Saving feature names for later use
feature_list = list(features.columns)

# Convert to numpy array
features = np.array(features)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# 30% examples in test data
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels,
                                                          stratify = labels,
                                                          test_size = 0.3,
                                                          random_state = 0)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(train, train_labels)

print(np.mean(train_labels))
print(train_labels.shape)

print('accuracy on train: {:.5f}'.format(knn.score(train, train_labels)))
print('accuracy on test: {:.5f}'.format(knn.score(test, test_labels)))
```

output:

```
0.0023654350798950337
(81169,)
accuracy on train: 0.99763
accuracy on test: 0.99761
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have many more instances of 0 than 1 is an example of *class imbalance*. [Here is a really cool stats.stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models) on the topic.

Basically, if only 169 out of your 80000 labels are 1 and the rest are 0, then your model could naively predict the label 0 for *every* instance, and still have a training-set accuracy (= fraction of misclassified instances) of 99.78875%.

I suggest trying the F1 score, which is the harmonic mean of precision, AKA positive predictive value = TP/(TP + FP), and recall, AKA sensitivity = TP/(TP + FN): https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
print('F1 score on train: {:.5f}'.format(f1_score(train, train_labels)))
print('F1 score on test:  {:.5f}'.format(f1_score(test, test_labels)))
```

Comment: duh! this makes a lot of sense. But now I am getting the error:  "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets"

Comment: @user3107977, sorry, I forgot to mention that unlike the built-in method `knn.score()`, to use a different evaluation metric, you need to first generate a vector of predictions using `yhat_train = knn.predict(train)` and `yhat_test = knn.predict(test)`, and then pass these predictions to the scoring function with `f1_score(yhat_train, train_labels)` and `f1_score(yhat_test, test_labels)`.